# How to push from Cloud VM to cloud repository?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-source-repos

I committed a model from google cloud source repo to cloud VM and trained on it. After training I would like to commit the changes back to the cloud repo. How to do that in the terminal?

Comment: When you followed the document [1](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#linux-or-macos), you added the repository as a remote then you were able to push to a Google Cloud repository.

Comment: Add details such as how you configured git authorization, the command you are using, and error messages.

Comment: @Danny if you already resolved your issue, provide your answer and other details of error that you fix, to help other communities.